# Sorting numbers containing commas

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am trying to sort a column of numbers using commas, eg 1,092,021. The sorting is treating the , as a decimal and sorting improperly. eg:

```
1,330,000
2,350,000
3
5
7,000,000
etc
```

Is there a way to get the comma separated numbers to sort properly?

Comment: Quick workaround is to remove commas, then sort, and then add them back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution @JaredT proposed:

```
var nums = ['1,330,000', '2,350,000', '3', '5', '7,000,000', '1,000', '100'];

nums
    .map(function (n) { return parseInt(n.replace(/,/g, ''));})
    .sort(function (a, b) { return a > b;})
    .map(function (i) {
        return String(i).split('')
            .reverse()
            .map(function (n, i) {
                return n + (!i || (i % 3) ? '' : ',');
            })
            .reverse()
            .join('');
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Magomogo. I added this sorter function to the column:

`sorter: function commas(a,b){`
      `a = parseInt(a.replace(/,/g, ''));`
      `b = parseInt(b.replace(/,/g, ''));`
      `if (a < b) return 1;`
         `if (a > b) return -1;`
         `return 0;`
    `},`

Answer (score 1):

I did the same as @vinnie-james and it works fine. I share my code.

```
'columns': [{
            field:'Checkbox'
          },{
            field:'Status'
          },{
            field:'Price',
            visible:true,
            sorter: function commas(a,b){ a = parseInt(a.replace(/,/g, '')); b = parseInt(b.replace(/,/g, '')); if (a < b) return 1; if (a > b) return -1; return 0; }]
```